# animateKeyframesWithDuration make screen Not responding after animation

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

I use `animateKeyframesWithDuration` to simple animate my view:

```
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:0 animations:^{
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        containerView.center = CGPointMake(containerView.center.x, 150);
    }];
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.5 relativeDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        containerView.center = oldCenter;
        
    }];

}completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    
}];
```

After the animation finished (completion block called with `finished = YES`), the `UIViewController` isn't responsive, e.g. I can't press any `UIButton` on top the `UIViewController`.

Why that?

Comment: faced the same problem, I have implemented "completeTransition" nevertheless after finishing interactive transition everything is stuck and completion block not called. Have you seen such a problem? By the way, there is no such problem with simple animate with duration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added this line in the completion block:

```
[transitionContext completeTransition:NO];
```

That fix my problem.